# ocr- My image wont recognize in tesseract ocr

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ocr

Hi Im currently new in Tesseract-ocr and I want to recognize my image when i take a picture.. Im using ionic framework to do that.. The capturing of image is fine it works well but when I click the button for the functionality of the ocr it does nothing.. I just followed the docs in https://github.com/gustavomazzoni/cordova-plugin-tesseract

This is my html

```
<ion-view view-title="OCR Testing">
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="startOCR()">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-camera"></i> Scanbot OCR
        </button>
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="scan()">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-camera"></i> Scan
        </button>
        <!--   <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-if="currentDocumentImage.originalImageFileUri" ng-click="startCroppingUi()">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-crop-strong"></i> Scanbot Cropping UI
    </button>
 -->
        <!-- <img ng-if="currentDocumentImage.imageFileUri" src="{{currentDocumentImage.imageFileUri}}" class="img-big-thumbnail padding"> -->
        <img ng-if="image" src="{{image}}" class="img-big-thumbnail padding">
        <code>{{text}}</code>

    </ion-content>
    </ion-views>
```

and this is my controller

```
.controller('ScanbotOCRCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera, DemoImageStorage, PhotoLibrary) {

    $scope.startOCR = function() {

      $scope.imageData = '';

        var options = {
            quality: 90,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 500,
            targetHeight: 500,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
                // correctOrientation: true
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            $scope.text = null;

            $timeout(function() {
                // DOM has finished rendering
                // insert here the call to TesseractPlugin.recognizeText function to recognize the text
                $scope.imageData = $scope.image;

            });


        }, function(err) {
            // error
            console.log('ERROR with camera plugin. Error: ' + err);
        });

    };


    $scope.scan = function() {

        window.TesseractPlugin.recognizeText($scope.imageData, language, function(recognizedText) {
            $scope.text = recognizedText;
            alert(recognizedText);
        }, function(reason) {
            console.log('Error on recognizing text from image. ' + reason);
        });


    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or what?

Comment: No i dont get any errors when i clicked the button its just does nothing. I change the 'console.log' to 'alert' because im debugging that using a phone

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late but here is the solution.

Directly feed the original data returned by the getPicture() function i.e. imagedata without adding "data:image/jpeg;base64," before it. So it becomes:

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
        $scope.image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        $scope.text = null;
         //here, do it like this and feed it to tesseract
        $scope.imageData = imageData;
        });
```